# Removing the lower element between 2 arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code which compares two arrayLists and removes the lower hypotenuse and returns it.

```
public static GeometricShape removeLowerHypotenuse(ArrayList<GeometricShape> left, ArrayList<GeometricShape> right) {
    GeometricShape x = null;
    if(((RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHypotenuse() < ((RightTriangle)left.get(0)).getHypotenuse() && right.size() != 0 && left.size() != 0) {
        x = right.get(0);
        right.remove(0);
    }
    if(((RightTriangle)left.get(0)).getHypotenuse() < ((RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHypotenuse() && right.size() != 0 && left.size() != 0) {
        x = left.get(0);
        left.remove(0);
    }
    if(right.size() != 0 && left.size() == 0) {
        x = right.get(0);
    }
    if(right.size() == 0 && left.size() != 0) {
        x = left.get(0);
    }
    if(right.size() == 0 && left.size() == 0) {
        return left.get(0);
    }
    return x;
}
```

When both arrayLists have a size of 1 (1 element in each) I get an out of bounds exception and confused why this is. I dont see what im missing in my code.

Comment: You're checking the size *after* you already tried getting element at index 0. Check size first, and since you only care about first element, you might use `isEmpty()` instead of `size()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting **IndexOutOfBoundsException** it means you are trying to access object from the list using such index value whose value is greater that list size.You always need to take care about this  while working with list,arrays.

In your case **IndexOutOfBoundsException** will occure when your **very first** if condition executed in that you are removing object from **right** list.

When both list size is 1 and you removed **one object** from **right** list the size of right list becomes **0**. In your very next if condition  you are trying this

**RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHyp**otenuse()
when there is size of **right** list is **0**. so there is nothing in list on **index 0**
This is reason you are getting **IndexOutOfBoundsException** in your code

change your conditions and check size first before doing any operations on list as follows

```
public static GeometricShape removeLowerHypotenuse(ArrayList<GeometricShape> left, ArrayList<GeometricShape> right) {
        GeometricShape x = null;
        if(right.size() != 0 && left.size() != 0 && ((RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHypotenuse() < ((RightTriangle)left.get(0)).getHypotenuse()  ) {
            x = right.get(0);
            right.remove(0);
        }
        if(right.size() != 0 && left.size() != 0 && ((RightTriangle)left.get(0)).getHypotenuse() < ((RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHypotenuse() ) {
            x = left.get(0);
            left.remove(0);
        }
        if(right.size() != 0 && left.size() == 0) {
            x = right.get(0);
        }
        if(right.size() == 0 && left.size() != 0) {
            x = left.get(0);
        }
        if(right.size() == 0 && left.size() == 0) {
            return left.get(0);
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Still you will get **IndexOutOfBoundsException**  with this code as in last condition you are trying to access from empty list you need to change this code in your last if

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was because once the size was 0 it would throw an error, didn't realize that the order made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `else if()` rather than `if()` for this, like so:

```
if(right.size() != 0 && left.size() == 0) {
    x = right.get(0);
}
else if(right.size() == 0 && left.size() == 0) {
    x =  left.get(0);
}
else if(right.size() == 0 && left.size() != 0) {
    x = left.get(0);
}
else if(((RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHypotenuse() < ((RightTriangle)left.get(0)).getHypotenuse() && right.size() != 0 && left.size() != 0) {
    x = right.get(0);
    right.remove(0);
}
else if(((RightTriangle)left.get(0)).getHypotenuse() < ((RightTriangle)right.get(0)).getHypotenuse() && right.size() != 0 && left.size() != 0) {
    x = left.get(0);
    left.remove(0);
}
```

In your code, if the ArrayList `right` had one element, and if the first `if()` case was true, then the first element of `right` would be removed, leaving it `null`.

In the subsequent `if()` statement, when `right.get(0)` is called, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.
Hence, you shold use else-if statements.

Also, if either of the ArrayLists is empty, then by your code, in the first if statement, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` would be thrown. Hence, I've rearranged some of the conditions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException  in second if when both list will have size 0